# How to escape Freemarker output of captured assign?

Tags: java, html, frontend, escaping, freemarker

I want to escape the output of a variable, that used the capture syntax of a `<#assign>` in Example 2.

Example 1:

```
<#assign test1='{"json": "more"}' />
<div data-test1="${test1}"></div>
```

Output (escaped):

```
<div data-test1="{&quot;json&quot;: &quot;more&quot;}"></div>
```

Example 2:

```
<#assign test2><@compress single_line=true>
{
  "json": "because it is more complex with list, if else etc."
}
</@compress></#assign>
<div data-test2="${test2}"></div>
```

Output (not escaped):

```
<div data-test2="{ "json": "because it is more complex with list, if else etc." }"></div>
```

This is exactly how the [docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html) are describing this feature. Also the [docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html#dgui_misc_autoescaping_nonmarkupof) for escaping.

I need to use the second example, because `test2` is more complex to generate.
Is there a way to force the escaping or to convert the non-markup output to markup? I tried `?esc`, `<#outputformat>` `<#autoesc>`, reassigning to another variable.
Nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the section where you capture that generated JSON inside `<#outputformat "JSON">...</#outputformat>`. (`plainText`, or any non-markup output format also will work well, as far as not suppressing escaping inside a markup goes.)

```
<#outputformat "JSON">
<#assign test2><@compress single_line=true>
{
  "json": "because it is more complex with list, if else etc."
}
</@compress></#assign>
</#outputformat>
<div data-test2="${test2}"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the `<#outputformat>` inside the `<#assign>` block and that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it has to be outside the `#assign`, otherwise you capture a HTML fragment that has another type of output in the middle of it. But as the outer shell is already HTML, it will be assumed that it needs no more escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Convert the markup output to string via builtin `?markup_string`. Then it will be escaped automatically.

```
<div data-test2="${test2?markup_string}"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div data-test2="{ &quot;json&quot;: &quot;because it is more complex with list, if else etc.&quot; }"></div>
```

Comment: People can forget to add `?markup_string` where they use the variable, so it's risky to build on that. But see my answer.